# Can't detect my TV using HDMI

Tags: hdmi, tv

I have tried to watch a movie on TV by connecting my lap top using HDMI cable. But I couldn't connect it. I have tried several codes. Now I have faced another problem as Red color dot on right top corner which I can not get rid of.

[image: Red dot screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried setting up a second monitor through settings > Screen Display ?

Comment: there is no any screen display setting

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu ?

Comment: 18.04 LTS  .. have any idea to fix it ?

Comment: 18.04 has the settings path I mentioned. I use it too.